# I'd like to include Markdown in a LaTeX file

Tags: templates, include, markdown

I have a LaTeX file, `foo.tex` and a bunch of [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) files `{1..N}.markdown` in the same directory.  Basically, I'd like to be able to `\include{1.markdown}` and have *the markdown rendered to LaTeX* and included in `foo.tex`.  How can I do this?

The closest I can come up with is [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) which lets me define a template and variables at the command line.  This can obviously work, but is cumbersome and annoying.  Is there any better solution?

Comment: What about having pandoc, or one of the other Markdown engines that can output LaTeX (such as maruku), convert each file individually and then including the converted files in `foo.tex`?

Comment: Yep!  A quick bash loop can keep that up to date and compile `foo.tex` and so on, but it's nice to have that hook into my AucTeX workflow in emacs, and of course I could write that too, but I was hoping for a quick-and-easy that would be easy to rely on for people who don't have my particular setup. [Aditya's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31159/id-like-to-include-markdown-in-a-latex-file/31185#31185) seems to do exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For ConTeXt, I have written a module, `t-filter`, that provides a nice user-interface for running external programs on a file. Using that module, you can write:

```
\usemodule[filter]

\defineexternalfilter
    [markdown]
    [filter={pandoc -t context -o \externalfilteroutputfile}]
```

after which you can use

```
 \processmarkdownfile{....}
```

to convert a markdown file to context and input the resulting back to tex. (The `\defineexternalfilter` command also creates an environment `\startmarkdown ... \stopmarkdown`. The module writes the contents of this environment to an external file, processes   file through `pandoc`, and inputs the result.)

This is essentially a glorified wrapper around `\write18`. For a one-off task, you can use:

```
\newcommand\processmarkdownfile[1]
    {\immediate\write18{pandoc -t latex -o #1.tex #1}%
     \input{#1.tex}}
```

and then use `\processmarkdownfile{...}` to include a markdown file in LaTeX. You need to enable `write18` for this to work. The easiest method is to pass `-shell-escape` to `pdflatex`:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape <filename>
```

The `t-filter` module provides other goodies as well (use an sub directory to store temp files, do not rerun the filter if the file has not changed, etc.). If you  want, it is easy to add an interface for them in LaTeX as well.

Answer (score 7):

There is a [markdown parser](https://github.com/jgm/lunamark) written in lua, which can output LaTeX, ConTeXt and other format. It should not be hard to write a small wrapper to use it to parse markdown files in luatex (ConTeXt already includes a parser based on it).

Answer (score 6):

This thread is quite old now, but in case someone will come here in the future looking for the solution **there is now a [dedicated LaTeX markdown package](https://ctan.org/pkg/markdown)**.

This seems to do exactly what was needed in the initial question.

Comment: The OP states that "I'd like to be able to `\include{1.markdown}` *and* have the markdown rendered to LaTeX and included in `foo.tex`" (*italic* is mine), but I think that using `\markdownInput{file.md}` of the markdown package should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

The `wiki` package of the [`nicetext`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicetext) allows to typeset this kind of files. However, I can't tell you if it supports Markdown fully or at all. There are a couple of different similar formats around.

Note that the documentation of `nicetext` is incomplete, which doesn't make things easier.